# steps for finding inverse tangent

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

My textbook gives me this:

[image]

Can someone please walk me through the steps to get -pi/3 from the inverse tangent?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By definition, $\tan^{-1} (k)$ is the angle in $\left(-\frac{\pi}{2}, \frac{\pi}{2}\right)$ whose tangent is $k$.

Now, to find $\tan^{-1}(-\sqrt{3})$, you have to look a the right half of the unit cicle and find the angle that has a tangent of $-\sqrt{3}$. On the right half of the unit circle, the common angles from $\left(-\frac{\pi}{2}, \frac{\pi}{2}\right)$ are:

$$ \frac{\pi}{3}, \frac{\pi}{4}, \frac{\pi}{6}, 0, -\frac{\pi}{6}, -\frac{\pi}{4}, \mbox{ and }-\frac{\pi}{3}. $$

If you look at the $(x,y)$ coordinates of these $7$ angles, you will find that -$\frac{\pi}{3}$ has the coordinate $\left(\frac{1}{2}, -\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}\right)$, and the tangent of this angle would be $\frac{y}{x} = -\sqrt{3}$.

Thus, the angle on the right half of the unit circle that has a tangent of $-\sqrt{3}$ is -$\frac{\pi}{3}$, which means that $\tan^{-1}(-\sqrt{3}) = -\frac{\pi}{3}$.

Answer (score 0):

$\tan^{-1} \dfrac{y}{x}=\tan^{-1} (-\sqrt{3})$

What is $\tan (-x)$? It can be written as $-\tan{x}$.

Therefore,$ \tan^{-1} (-\sqrt{3})=-  \tan^{-1} (\sqrt{3})=y$, $\tan y= \sqrt{3}$. Now you know what's the value of $y$.

Answer (score 0):

It's just that $\tan(-\pi/3)=-\sqrt{3}$. If you don't know it use a calculator. There is not more to it.